# Update json string column with proper json in Postgres SQL

Tags: postgresql, json

I have a column which type is JSON but it contains JSON strings like this:

```
"{\"a\":1,\"b\":2,\"c\":3}"
```

I want to update the values in the column with proper JSON objects without the quotes and escapes like this:

```
{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}
```

I've tried the following statement even tough it says it does update rows, the columns are still the same.

```
UPDATE table SET column = to_json(column);
```

And when I tell him that the values are text it just adds additional escape backslashes in the output.

```
UPDATE table SET column = to_json(column:text)
```

This results in this monstrosity

```
"\"{\\\"a\\\":1,\\\"b\\\":2,\\\"c\\\":3,\\\"}\""
```

It seems like the `to_json` function doesn't work since it is a JSON string?

How can I update those values?

Comment: Please do [not crosspost](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/157328). Already asked (and answered) here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75243698/